# Javascript to Highlight Table Row Only When inside 'a' tag is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

I currently have a html table (with 2 columns) and I am trying to add various effects to this table such as table row hover effect, table click effect, etc...This is the script I am using now and its working fine so far:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){   

    //the following script is to change the table row bg color when clicked
    $('tr').click(function(){
    $('tr td').css({ 'background' : 'none'});
    $('td', this).css({ 'background-color' : '#CCC' });
  }); 

    //the following script is for the table row hover effect
    $('tr').hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFF99');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            $(this).contents('td').css('border', 'none');
        });


});  
</script>

</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td> <a href="#">Movie Part 1</a></td>
<td>01:23:26</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> <a href="#">Movie Part 1</a></td>
<td>01:23:26</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
```

From the above template, you can see that I am having 2 columns for this table and 1 columns has the  tag with the href link and the other column doesnt have any  tag.

Like I mentioned above, the script I am using to highlight the table row when clicked works. But I am trying to slightly modify the script so that it only execute the click effect only when the "a" tag inside the "tr td" is clicked. Right now, the table row is highlighted doesnt matter where I click inside the 'tr' area. It also highlights even if I click the second column inside the 'tr' which has no link.

**How can I modify this above script so it highlights the entire table row ONLY when the 'a' tag inside the table row's first column is clicked?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### jQuery 1.7.x :

```
$('tr').on('click','a', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').css({ 'background-color' : '#ccc'});
});
```

I'm thinking that you only need to change the background color of the `TR` and not the `TD`. If I'm mistaken, just use this instead:

```
$('tr').on('click','a', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').children('td').css({ 'background-color' : '#ccc'});
});
```

#### jQuery 1.6.x and below :

```
$('tr').delegate('a', 'click', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').children('td').css({ 'background-color' : '#ccc' });
});
```

#### EDIT

As per your comment below, you want to *revert* a row back to a normal background color when another row is clicked.

To do that efficiently, I'd suggest you resort to CSS rules. Heck, come to think of it, we should have done that even as the question was first answered.

First, define CSS rules like so:

```
tr { background-color:#fff; /* or your default */ }
tr.selected { background-color:#ddd; /* or your selected color */ }
```

then switch that using jQuery:

```
$('tr').delegate('a', 'click', function () {
    $(this)
        .closest('tr').addClass('selected')
        .siblings('tr').removeClass('selected')
        ;
});
```

If just modifying the `tr` does not work for you, modify your CSS rules like so:

```
tr td { background-color:#fff; /* or your default */ }
tr.selected td { background-color:#ddd; /* or your selected color */ }
```

Comment: hi richard, The reason I was changing the bg color for the TDs instead of TR was cuz I thought the bg color for tr cant be changed directly. So I read somewhere that to achieve this, the best way is to change the tr color instead. Not sure if thats correct..

Comment: Also, I tried out your suggested code by it doesnt highlight the tr row to #CCC color. Even the tr hover color that I also have on the same page stops working too..

Comment: my code above assumes jQuery 1.7 and above (for the `.on` function). Let me update it, just in case you're using a lower version.

Comment: thank you richard...yeah the last one you updated works for me since I use jquery 1.6.2. Thank you so much for that...

Comment: just need help with one more small modification for this code. At the moment, this script doesnt undo the previous row highlighted when a new row is clicked. It continues to highlight the clicked rows. how can I modify it so it only highlights only one row at a time?

Comment: wow Richard...thats it! Thank you for explaining it so simple and it makes sense. I tested it out and it also works. However, for the css bit, I used the "tr.selected td" and it works for me. Thank you for looking ahead and mentioning that bit as well. Looking at the code now, its looks easy to understand on what the script does but this is something I wouldnt have been able to write by myself. I checked out your profile - u r 2 yrs younger than me but A LOT more smarter. lol.. Thank you again richard for your help...much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to check if an 'a' is below the 'tr' with href

```
$('tr').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.href){
        $('tr td').css({
            'background': 'none'
        });
        $('td', this).css({
            'background-color': '#CCC'
        });
    }
});
```

*PS. Thanks to Richard Neil Ilagan for the head's up on the exception thrown by using if (e.target.href.length > 0) due to event bubbling.*

Comment: thank you xepterx. I tried this code but it works the same way as it did before. Meaning, the row gets highlighted even when the td column with no "a" link is clicked. Inside that table row, 1 column has a link and 2nd column only has simple text with no link to it. Maybe your script is picking up the link that I have in the 1st column and still highlighting the row even when the second column is clicked. But I am trying to find a way that if the second column is clicked nothing happens BUT if the first column with the link is clicked, it highlights that row. Does it make sense?

Comment: ah, i thought you wanted to highlight rows that has an anchor. well, i've updated the code, so this should be what you are looking for

Comment: I wonder if it would be better to check for `$(this).is('[href]')` instead. Hmm. I'm thinking that your code will throw an exception if I clicked on something without an `href` attribute.

Comment: nope, the code won't throw an exception because clicking on something without an href attribute would not event trigger the event

Comment: yes it would --- because you're attaching the handler on the `tr`. anything inside the `tr` would trigger the event due to event bubbling.

Comment: here, have fun. http://jsfiddle.net/richardneililagan/sPJ3y/ best to check for `href` first, I guess. `if (e.target.href && e.target.href.length > 0)`.

Comment: yeah, you are right about it throwing an exception, this would work just fine without throwing an exception, if(e.target.href).

Thanks for the advice =)

Comment: thank you xepterX for that..I really appreciate your help. I tried out richard's code that he had suggested and it works well. I havent been able to get this code to work though..thank you again xepterX.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

http://jsbin.com/enariy/edit#javascript,html

Comment: hi mhps, I tried the code you had given in the link, but when I click the table row using this code, it doesnt highlight it to the #CCC color.